# `defaultYesodMiddleware` and `authorizationCheck` are part of a hidden package, is there any way to reuse these?

Tags: module, dry, yesod, middleware

I'm currently trying to write a Yesod Middleware for my library, and I merely want to add some functionality ad-hoc to the default functionality that Yesod provides. You can view the default implementation from [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.12/docs/src/Yesod-Core-Class-Yesod.html#yesodMiddleware). I don't want to overload my package with unneeded dependencies, but I feel like having `defaultYesodMiddleware` hidden is only encouraging it. Also, looking at `authorizationCheck`, I have a feeling I will need to include a handful of modules to make it work. Are there any easy ways around this, to keep your code base clean? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a case where I forgot to expose the identifiers. Version 1.2.14 of yesod-core includes these two functions.